# How to ensure HTTP trigger will be called only via HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, firebase, https, google-cloud-functions

I'm building an API on Cloud Functions with NodeJS and Express (Firebase) and I'd like to accept only calls via HTTPs so calls made over plain HTTP will fail.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Not sure if there is an easy way to do it using express but you can get the protocol from the [X-Forwarded-Proto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should examine the request object being passed to your function.  It's going to be an Express type [Request](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) object.  Request has a property called [protocol](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.protocol) that should be "https".  So:

```
functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    if (req.protocol !== "https") {
        // reject the request
        res.sendStatus(403)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Generaly you want a application running for each protocol listening to a different port. To solve your problem you could simply ignore the requests for the http instance or redirect every http request to a https request.

Here's a middleware for that:

```
app.use(function(request, response){
  if(!request.secure){
    response.redirect("https://" + request.headers.host + request.url);
  }
});
```

See the express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#app.listen).

Comment: This doesn't apply to Cloud Functions callable functions.  There is no express middleware exposed (even though the OP tagged this with Express, it's just not involved).

Comment: I tried to use this `req.secure` variable making a Postman call, but it always says it's secure.

Comment: @AlissonEnz `req.secure` is equivalent to manually checking for http protocol [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html#req.secure), can we see come code to triangulate the problem.